# ngCordova SQLite no funciona en Android 6.0 o superior

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, cordova, ng-cordova

Buenas comunidad, probando mi aplicacion, no funciona el plugin **SQLite** y el plugin para detectar el tipo de Red a la que esta conectado el dispositivo de ngCordova para Android, cuando intento ingresar aparecen estos mensajes.

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1216 
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:1216 
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:1216 
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
```

Y cuando ingreso a una de las vistas, y debe mostrarme información al respecto me aparece esto.

```
database already open: unicesar.db SQLitePlugin.js:106 
new transaction is waiting for open operation SQLitePlugin.js:80 DB 
opened: unicesar.db
```

Tengo un dispositivo con android 4.2.2 y funciona perfectamente, pero en varios dispositivos con Android 6.0 o superior no me muestra nada.

Mi configuración de la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
 db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
            name: "unicesar.db",
            location: "default"
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve un problema similar con Android e iOS, intenta hacerlo asi :

Dentro de tu `app.js`, especificamente dentro del metodo `run`

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    //Aqui declaras tus tablas
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....");
});
```

Y en tus controladores :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    var db = null;
    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'unicesar.db', location: 'default' });
    } else {
        db = window.openDatabase("unicesar.db", '1.0', 'Tu DB', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    }
});
```

**EDICION**

Reemplaza :

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
    name: "unicesar.db",
    location: "default"
});
```

Por :

```
var db = null;
if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'unicesar.db', location: 'default' });
} else {
    db = window.openDatabase("unicesar.db", '1.0', 'Tu DB', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
}
```

Te aconsejo, que dentro de tu `app.js` inicialices la base de datos y desde los controladores solo accedas y ejecutes las consultas pertinentes.

app.js

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
     var db = null;

     if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
         var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'unicesar.db', location: 'default' });
     } else {
         var db = window.openDatabase("unicesar.db", '1.0', 'Fepachi DB', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
     }
     crearTablaPerfil = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Estudiante(Cedula integer primary key, Nombre text, Apellido text," +
         " Rol integer, Facultad text, Programa text, Semestre integer)";
     crearTablaHorario = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Horario(Codigo text primary key, Grupo integer," +
         "Nombre text, Creditos integer, Dia text, Hora text, Lugar text, Profesor text)";
     crearTablaCalificaciones = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Calificaciones(Codigo text primary key, Grupo integer," +
         "NombreAsig text, Nota1 float, Nota2 float, Nota3 float, Habilitacion float)";
     crearTablaTareasEstu = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TareasEstu(Fila integer primary key, Texto text, Fecha text)";
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaPerfil);
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaHorario);
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaCalificaciones);
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaTareasEstu);
 });
```

Comment: Pero en mi caso, la base de datos, solo la creo al momento de dar click, y consulto cuando ingreso a una interfaz, como seria en mi caso?

Comment: como cuando haces click? la idea es que las tablas se creen al momento de iniciar la app, quizas acceder a la base de datos cuando hagas click, pero tambien inicializarla debiese quedar desde un principio, puedes agregar tu codigo para ver como lo estas haciendo? @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Comment: Claro, deja te paso codigo espera

Comment: Aqui esta este enlace [enalce](https://pastebin.com/FFtbE0VV), echale un ojo, en mi caso creo la bd, y luego las tablas, cuando la información requerida sea enviada, eso ocurre bien, el problema es al momento de la consulta.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales actualice!

Comment: Disculpa, mi pregunta pero al hacer eso, que me dices, no tendría que cambiar la forma en que inserto, y consulto por que estoy usando el plugin,  o eso no cambia nada?

Comment: No, eso no cambia nada. @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Comment: ok, empiezo a probar a ver que tal

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59559/discussion-between-sioesi-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).

Comment: Funciono a la perfeccion, eres un capo maestro, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: jaja cualquier duda sobre estos temas, aqui estaremos!, estoy trabajando con ionic 1 asi que mas o menos lo manejo! saludos!